# Will modification of one replica change other two replicas as well?

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop have 3 replication factor, right ?

If I modify one replica, will the other two replicas also change or not ?

Answer (score 0):

But you can't modify the contents of file on hadoop because it is **'write once read many'**.So,you first modify it locally and then replicate it on hdfs.So,then the contents of 3 replication are same.

Comment: In other words, you "overwrite" the file on HDFS with the local edits

Comment: is there any way to overcome "overwrite" the file on HDFS `@cricket_007`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, HDFS uses a replication factor equal to 3 but it can be changed. HDFS does not allow to alter just one copy of your data block, because block replication should be transparent for the user.

Technically, you can alter one copy by accessing the local file system of a single datanode, and alter the files under the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` local direcory, but HDFS is not aware of this change, therfore it will not be replicated for the other copies.